# Heroku Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When trying to do rake or console command on Heroku, I keep getting this error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:725:19)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:480:20)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:528:19)
    at /Users/bashar/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/got.js:75:15
    at Array.map (native)
    at getCerts (/Users/bashar/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/got.js:72:20)
    at addToOpts (/Users/bashar/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/got.js:85:15)
    at got (/Users/bashar/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/got.js:104:27)
    at request (/Users/bashar/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node_modules/heroku-cli-util/lib/rollbar.js:9:10)
```

Any idea?